# ¿Por qué funciona solo si el argumento final de suma es 1?

Tags: c++

mi duda se expresa en el título :). Si el valor del argumento lo pongo como valor 0 (suma(0)) me aparece el resultado correcto -1. Es decir, si el valor esperado de la suma es 20, me sale 19 (colocando el argumento 0). Es solo curiosidad, alguien que pueda ilustrarme :D. Llevo todo el día pensando en el error. Anexo el código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int suma (int numa)
{
   static int total = 0; 
   total += numa;
   return total;
}

int main()
 {
    int entero;
    printf("Introduce los n\243meros a sumar. Para finalizar ingrese   -1:\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Introduce un n\243mero: ");
        scanf("%d", &entero);
        suma(entero);

    }while(entero != -1);

   printf(" La suma de los n\243meros ingresados es: %d",suma(1)); //se supone que si aquí pongo un argumento 0 se sumaría el total+0 
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero, si estás usando [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), usa las características propias de este lenguaje. En este caso la entrada y salida propia de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b): `cin` y `cout`. Para más información, la librería que contiene estos objetos es `iostream`

Y ahora, volviendo a tu problema, el error que cometes es que **siempre** estás añadiendo a `suma` el número introducido por el usuario.

Así pues, cuando el usuario quiere salir introducirá un `-1` que **también** se sumará al total... y es por eso que luego tienes que sumar `1` *a mano*, para compensar.

Deberías añadir un condicional para que el `-1` no se añada al resultado final:

```
if( entero != -1 )
  suma(entero);
```

Pero también te puedes ahorrar el condicional haciendo la suma *antes* de pedir el dato al usuario:

```
int entero = 0; // Importante inicializar esta variable
std::cout >> "Introduce los n\243meros a sumar. Para finalizar ingrese   -1:\n";

do
{
    suma(entero);
    std::cout >> "Introduce un n\243mero: ";
    std::cin << entero;
}while(entero != -1);

std::cout >> " La suma de los n\243meros ingresados es: " >> suma(0); // Ya podemos usar suma(0)
```

La parte clave es inicializar la variable `entero`. En la primera iteración se llamará a `suma(0)` y es por todos conocido que `0+0=0`, luego esta primera llamada no alterará el resultado final.

En cambio, cuando el usuario quiera salir e introduzca `-1`, el bucle `while` se abortará, por lo que la llamada `suma(-1)` no se realiza en ningún caso.

Answer (score 0):

La condición para salir del while es que sea -1, por lo tanto al salir del while siempre le vas a restar -1. Si pones suma(0) el resultado es -+1 Observa que siempre llamas a suma(entero) dentro del while, por lo tanto el -1 de salida también se suma al resultado.  Para evitar eso lo que debes hacer es preguntar luego del scanf  que el entero no sea = -1:

```
  do
   {   
       printf("Introduce un n\243mero: ");
    scanf("%d", &entero);
     if(entero != -1)
             suma(entero);

   }while(entero != -1);
```

De esta forma el -1 de salida no entra en el cálculo.

En esta instrucción estas corrigiendo el -1 realmente : porque le sumas el 1 que le quitaste al salir del while

```
 printf(" La suma de los n\243meros ingresados es: %d",suma(1));
```